# UIAlertView close the App

Tags: iphone, uialertview

in my project my app first tries to connect to the internet, but now i have to check if there is an connection available!
so i made an if, else within an UIAlertView in the else part!

but how can i close the whole app on a click on the following button?

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Keine Internetverbindung" message:@"Es konnte keine Verbindung zu www.sip.de hergestellt werden!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Schliessen" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

thank you all for helping beforehand

greets Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.h file

@interface UntitledViewController : UIViewController < UIAlertViewDelegate > {
}

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Keine Internetverbindung" message:@"Es konnte keine Verbindung zu www.sip.de hergestellt werden!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Schliessen" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    exit(0);
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Its not working in ios5 . Any other method possible to quit the app.

Comment: I can confirm that @NewXcoder is correct. What other method would work?

Comment: You're not allowed to exit(0) on iOS, it works, but apple rejects apps that use exit();

Comment: Guys, this was answered 3 years ago. It worked, not sure if it still works now.

Answer (score 0):

UIalertViewConfigure:

UIAlertView *applicationExitAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Exit" message:@"Are You wanto to exits this App" delegate:self               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

[applicationExitAlert show];
[applicationExitAlert release];

UIAlertViewDelegate:

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
  if (buttonIndex == 1) {
  exit(0);
  }
  }

i hope its work